# JavaScript Namespace Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces, closures, global

I've been trying to make my javascript code better by creating a namespace for my code so that there are no global variable/function clashes and also putting everything in the namespace in an anonymous function so everything is private unless explicitly expressed otherwise through the return statement. 

Atm, I'm getting a "Uncaught Type Error: object is not a function"

```
var Namespace = (function() {
    //private variables/functions
    var a;
    var b;
    function priv_func1() {
        //do stuff
    }

    //public variables/functions
    return {
        pub_var1: b,
        pub_func1: function() {
            //do stuff
        }
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myName = new Namespace();
    myName.pub_func1();
}
```

So when I remove the () at the end of the Namespace definition which turns the function declaration into a function expression, I get no error, but in the examples I've seen they have the () in there, so I'm wondering what's going on.

I also put this at the start of the Namespace definition as well, to correct when the user accidentally omits the new keyword.

```
if (!(this instanceof Namespace))
        return new Namespace();
```

EDIT: Also, should I put my document ready function before or after the namespace definition.

Answer (score 2):

It works! You don'thave to use **new**, because you've not defined a `constructor`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   Namespace.pub_func1();
});
```

What you were trying ot do is accomplishded via `modules` wich create constructor.
Let me show you an example from *Javascript: Design Patterns*

### Modules That Create Constructors

> [..] but sometimes it’s
>   more convenient to create your objects using constructor functions. You can still do
>   that using the module pattern. The only difference is that the immediate function that
>   wraps the module will return a function at the end, and not an object.

Consider the following example of the module pattern that creates a constructor function

```
MYAPP.utilities.Array:
MYAPP.namespace('MYAPP.utilities.Array');
MYAPP.utilities.Array = (function () {
   // dependencies
   var uobj = MYAPP.utilities.object,
   ulang = MYAPP.utilities.lang,
   // private properties and methods...
   Constr;
   // end var
   // optionally one-time init procedures
   // ...
   // public API -- constructor
   Constr = function (o) {
      this.elements = this.toArray(o);
   };
   // public API -- prototype
   Constr.prototype = {
      constructor: MYAPP.utilities.Array,
      version: "2.0",
      toArray: function (obj) {
         for (var i = 0, a = [], len = obj.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            a[i] = obj[i];
         }
         return a;
      }
   };
   // return the constructor 
   // to be assigned to the new namespace
   return Constr;
}());

The way to use this new constructor will be like so:
var arr = new MYAPP.utilities.Array(obj);
```

Comment: Yeh I understand now. The (); at the end of Namespace means you don't have to define an object and assign it to the namespace. You can just use the namespace straight away.

Comment: @Michael: If you want to use the a constructor, you' ve to implement a namespace creating a constructor.